# How to use a local variable inside quotes in angular 4 (HTML) with ngFor?

Tags: html, angular, interpolation, ngfor

I'm using Angular2-Collapsible for my project. On clicking the table row, I want the details to be displayed. The code is attached below. Basically if I add `[detail]= "detail1"` then the collapsible-table-row-detail would be displayed on click. But since I'm using a for loop, I have to use the variable `i`. I've tried `[detail]= "'detail'+i"` and `[attr.detail]= "'detail'+i"`. Nothing seems to be working.

```
<collapsible-table [type]="'accordion'" borderedVertically="true" class="table">

 <thead class="table-heading">
   <collapsible-table-row>
     <th></th>
     <th>Reference ID</th>
     <th>Order ID</th>
     <th> OName</th>
     <th>FP</th>
     <th>SP</th>
      <th>Stat</th>
      <th>date</th>

   </collapsible-table-row>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
   <collapsible-table-row  *ngFor="let detail of details; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i" [detail]="'detail'{{i}}">

     <td><div class="input-group-text">
     <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
   </div>
 </td>
     <td (click)="showFirst=!showFirst"><i class="material-icons" *ngIf="showFirst"><span class="bulleticon"> - </span></i><i class="material-icons" *ngIf="!showFirst"><span class="bulleticon"> + </span> </i>{{detail.Reference_Id}}<br></td>
     <td> {{detail.OId}} </td>
     <td>{{detail.OName}}</td>
     <td>{{detail.FP}}</td>
     <td>{{detail.SP}}</td>
     <td>{{detail.Stat}} </td>
     <td>{{detail.date}}</td>


   </collapsible-table-row>
   <collapsible-table-row-detail #detail1 class="hidden-table">
       <div class="container">
         <div class="list col-5">
             <span class="heading">  Order details </span>
             <ul class="unorderedlist">
               <li> data1  </li>
               <li> data2 </li>
               <li> data3</li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
   </tbody>

   </collapsible-table-row-detail>
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here's a stackblitz implmentation of what I'm trying to acheive. I've used [detail]= "detail1" for demo purposes. But I need to use a variable "i" in the for loop.
Visit https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fw5upv.

Comment: have you tried `[detail]="'detail1'+i"` ?

Comment: yes. Basically I need [detail]="detail1" and the value 1 has to increment every time the for loop executes.

Comment: so no need to add `1` static just use `[detail]="'detail'+i"`

Comment: Can't you get the details element by its index, from the array? details[i]

Comment: No I'm not able to use the array index. I've attached the stackblitz implementation. Could you take a look?

Comment: I am updated html code in post. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 [detail]=" 'detail' + i "
```

Or

```
 detail="detail{{i}}"
```

Comment: My bad, force of habit, it's more clear (clearer ?) to me, thank you for pointing that out !

Comment: Cool, Anyways OP mentioned in question that he has already tried your way :p

Comment: Not the second one apparently !

Comment: Tried Both, didn't work. I need [detail]="detail1". But the value 1 should be of the variable that increments after every for loop execution.

Comment: @BharatVk `[detail]="'detail'+i"` it should work, either problem is somewhere else then

Comment: Saying you tried is great, but 1) I don't see it in your code 2) I don't see it in your explanation 3) We have no sandbox to try it. If neither of my solutions work, the issue is with your code, because that's the two and only ways of injecting variables into attributes.

Comment: @BharatVk also, be sure to have **the exact same syntax** that I have. I see you mixed it with `[detail]="'detail'{{i}}"`, that may be why it doesn't work. Try copy pasting to be sure.

Comment: I was trying your solutions on the fly. The code seems to working fine because as i mentioned, when i use [detail]= "detail1", the hidden table is being displayed. But on using the variable, it's not. May the issue is with the for loop statement! I needed some help with that.

Comment: @trichetriche    [detail]="'detail'{{i}}" . On using this I get an error in the console which says " Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected". I tried it without the square brackets as in "detail= "'detail'{{i}}" . But no luck with that as well.

Comment: Then you need to make a [mcve] to reproduce the issue. Otherwise, I won't be able to help you. Use https://stackblitz.io to create it.

Comment: @trichetriche https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fw5upv Here's a stackblitz implementation of what i'm asking. I need to use i in place of [detail]="detail1"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let detail of details; let i = index" >   
       <collapsible-table-row [attr.data-index]="i" [detail]="detail1">

          <td>
             <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="checkbox" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input">
             </div>
         </td>
         <td >6565</td>
         <td> {{detail.oid}} </td>
         <td>{{detail.pname}}</td>
         <td>{{detail.price}}</td>
         <td>{{detail.qoh}}</td>
       </collapsible-table-row>
       <collapsible-table-row-detail #detail1 class="hidden-table">
          <div class="container">
             <div class="list col-5" >
                <span class="heading">  Order details </span>
                   <ul class="unorderedlist">
                      <li> data4 </li>
                      <li> data5</li>
                      <li> data6 </li>
                  </ul>
           </div>
         </div>
       </collapsible-table-row-detail>
     </ng-container>
   </tbody>
```

You can check in your stackblitz just replace the html code.

Comment: I think this should create `detail1` by indexing

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. :(

Comment: I am updating my post Please check this.

Comment: No you're not getting my point I think. You've passed [detail]="detail1". If I do that, I get the output no question. But since I'm using a for loop, I need to pass the variable as i in "detail" something like [detail]="'detail'+i". But it's not working.

Comment: Ok i understand. but why you need `[detail]="'detail'+i"` this can you tell me

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a method in your HTML like:

```
[detail]="getDetail(i)"
```

And then in your ts file:

```
getDetail(i: number) {
  return 'detail' + i;
}
```

I have not tried this myself, so I'm not sure if it will work.